# How to get the indexes of vertices that was finally rendered?

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine

What is the final stage that is still possible to return the indexes that was not clipped or culled or occluded, and that are going to be rendered?

Comment: You can't access indices in any shader. What are you trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to find those areas in mesh that are hidden from camera.

Comment: You could run the vertices of the mesh and check whether they are in the camera frustum. But that could be quite expensive.

Comment: @Everts: And it would give you wrong results. Triangles can be visible although all three corners are outside of the camera-frustum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question asked, there isn't one. All [vertex processing rendering stages](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Processing) happen *before* [triangle clipping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Clipping). As does [transform feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback). And fragment shaders don't get vertex *indices*; they only get the per-vertex values from the vertex processing stage, after interpolation.

In theory, you could do something like this. Your VS outputs an integer index for the vertex, taken from `gl_VertexID`. You would need a GS that takes the three indices and packages them together into a `flat uvec3`. Each output vertex would be given the same values. And then, the fragment shader could get the `uvec3` and write each of those indices out to a buffer via [SSBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) and an [atomic counter](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Atomic_Counter).

Of course, you'll get the same index multiple times (assuming that triangles share indices). But you can do it.

It just doesn't serve much point. Rendering part of a mesh is a lot more trouble than it's worth. For performance, it's better to render either all of it or none of it, based on its visibility. And detecting that is best done via [occlusion tests](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Occlusion_Query) on a different, less complex shape.